# Как объединить два фильтра в один на дату?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Два скрипта по отдельности прекрасно работают. Но если я допустим хочу выбрать какой то месяц определенного года то не получается.

Они нивелируют друг друга при последующем выборе.

Как обьединить их. Или что лучше сделать?

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.filter-months');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  filterByMonth(select.value);
});
filterByMonth(select.value);

function filterByMonth(month) {
  const valMonth = +month;
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.post-list .post-item');
  [...items].forEach((el) => {
    const attr = el.querySelector('.post-date').getAttribute('datetime');
    const date = new Date(attr);
    if (date.getMonth() === valMonth || valMonth == 12 ) {
      el.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      el.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  });
}

const selectYear = document.querySelector('.filter-years');

selectYear.addEventListener('change', function() {
  filterByYear(selectYear.value);
});
filterByYear(selectYear.value);

function filterByYear(year) {
  const valYear = +year;
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.post-list .post-item');
  [...items].forEach((el) => {
    const attr = el.querySelector('.post-date').getAttribute('datetime');
    const date = new Date(attr);
    if (date.getFullYear() === valYear || valYear == 12 ) {
      el.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      el.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.post-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.post-item {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-filter">
  <div class="filter-block">
    <select class="filter-months">
      <option selected="selected" value="12">All months</option>
      <option value="0">January</option>
      <option value="1">February</option>
      <option value="2">March</option>
      <option value="3">April</option>
      <option value="4">May</option>
      <option value="5">June</option>
      <option value="6">July</option>
      <option value="7">August</option>
      <option value="8">September</option>
      <option value="9">October</option>
      <option value="10">November</option>
      <option value="11">December</option>
    </select>
    <select class="filter-years">
      <option selected="selected" value="12">All years</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
      <option value="2019">2019</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <ul class="post-list">
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 1</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-11-01T13:29:31+00:00">November 1, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 2</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-10-04T11:27:22+00:00">October 4, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 3</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-03-21T15:52:31+00:00">March 21, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 4</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2017-01-16T13:12:32+00:00">January 16, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 4</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2018-05-16T13:12:32+00:00">January 16, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
    <li class="post-item">
      <h2 class="post-title">Привет мир - 4</h2>
      <p class="post-date" datetime="2016-01-16T13:12:32+00:00">January 16, 2017</p>
      <p class="post-desc">люлюлю</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const selectMonth = document.querySelector('.filter-months');
const selectYear = document.querySelector('.filter-years');

selectMonth.addEventListener('change', function() {
  filterByMonthAndYear(selectMonth.value, selectYear.value);
});
selectYear.addEventListener('change', function() {
  filterByMonthAndYear(selectMonth.value, selectYear.value);
});

filterByMonthAndYear(selectMonth.value, selectYear.value);

function filterByMonthAndYear(month, year) {
  const valMonth = +month;
  const valYear = +year;
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.post-list .post-item');
  [...items].forEach((el) => {
    const attr = el.querySelector('.post-date').getAttribute('datetime');
    const date = new Date(attr);
    if ((date.getMonth() == valMonth || valMonth == 12) &&
        (date.getFullYear() == valYear || valYear == 12)) {
      el.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      el.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  });
}
```